# We tooled down the street. What's the nuance?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

We tooled down the street. (tool=drive)

I feel this expression is not used these days. What did you feel (as native English speakers) when you read(past read) this sentence? Is this expression acceptable and idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sense is archaic in British English (and referred specifically to driving a *coach and horses*.  It exists in American English only in the slang "tool around* (meaning going for a drive without any specfic destination).  This is a usage that learners are unlikely to need.

See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tool_around and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tool#Verb